# I am facing issue in hibernate-envers auditing

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using hibernate-core version 4.3.1 with jpa 2.3.1. Will hibernate envers 5.3.1 support hibernate version 4.x for auditing?

Comment: You'll have a better response if you ask directly the contributors of Hibernate

Comment: The versions you mention are a bit misleading as there presently is no JPA 2.3.1 specification unless you're referring to something else as "JPA".  As for mixing Envers and Hibernate Core versions, its recommended you use the same matched version for consistency since Core is a dependency of Envers.